# Use Redis for Sort and Page data from Postgres with Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-redis

I have a very consuming query that returns a resultset that I need to sort and do paging to show to the user.

If the user wants to sort or want another page of results, I have to run the query again.

I'm studying doing a one time query, and put the results in Redis, so there the user can sort and do paginating freely, not impacting in database performance in postgres.

I use spring boot and spring data JPA.

What I though of doing is:

1 - the user do the search that starts the query

2 - Check if the resultset is already on redis (expires in 10 minutes)

3 - If resultset not on redis execute the query on postgres and populate redis

4 - Do sort (if the user asked) and return the page needed from redis

How can I accomplish that? Can someone point a direction...